# wso2is custom multifactor authentication

Tags: one-time-password, wso2-identity-server

For WSO2IS seems only XMPP custom authentication is used (documented). Is there a reasonable way to implement a custom OTP (like implementing an interface)? The idea is to enable use of OATH, HW OTP (VASCO, Gemalto, ..)

g.

Answer (score 0):

We have solved this problem by
 - custom logon page requiring additional OTP authentication
 - custom authenticator validating the current user's OTP
I hope it helps someone too..